# capturing screen area without caret

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, textbox

I'm using `Graphics.CopyFromScreen()` method to capture a snapshot of a control, whose HWND I have. The problem is that I want to avoid capturing the blinking caret. Is there a way to achieve this? I'm open to using an API call (`BitBlt`?) if that is what it takes.

Note: I have seen a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556639/how-do-i-capture-a-winform-window-to-a-bitmap-without-the-caret), but the problem is that my control is not a WinForms control, not even the standard EDIT class, so I don't have the luxuries like `DrawToBitmap()`. It is Excel's edit box that appears when you press F2 in a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that HideCaret and ShowCaret functions will help

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648406(v=vs.85).aspx
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648403(v=vs.85).aspx

To obtain handle of the control (Edit, ComobBox etc) that holds the caret 
you may use functions
  GetWindowThreadProcessId to obtain ThreadId
  GetGUIThreadInfo         to get handle of a caret holder

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx

```
[DllImport("User32",
           CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi,
           ExactSpelling = true,
           EntryPoint = "HideCaret",
           SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern Boolean HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("User32",
           CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi,
           ExactSpelling = true,
           EntryPoint = "ShowCaret",
           SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern Boolean ShowCaret(IntPtr hWnd);


// If the window you have to copy is in your process then 
// handle = IntPtr.Zero
// Otherwise your have to find it out via GetWindowThreadProcessId and GetGUIThreadInfo 

HideCaret(handle);

try {
  // Your code to capture the image 
}
finally {
  ShowCaret(handle);
}
```